# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FCM error: cannot have last checkin timestamp in future'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

As every app these days have firebase push notifications, so do our app. Everything works fine like sending notifications and all. But I started getting this error :

> **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FCM error: cannot have last checkin timestamp in future'**

logs for above error:

> **2019-03-26 15:27:49.375300+0530 appName[665:131254] * Assertion failure in -FIRInstanceIDCheckinPreferences hasValidCheckinInfo, /Users/username/Desktop/appName/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Firebase/InstanceID/FIRInstanceIDCheckinPreferences.m:66
>   2019-03-26 15:27:49.379038+0530 appName[665:131254] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FCM error: cannot have last checkin timestamp in future'**

Cause of error: User changes the device time to a date and time before the last checkin timestamp.

Firebase SDK version used is **5.19.0**

If user sets the device time to automatic, this error does not occur.
I'm not able to catch this exception as this is occurring even before **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

Any help regarding handling this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Did you test the behaviour in release mode. Read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037935/swift-assertions-behaviour-in-production-applications

Comment: Not happening in release mode. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an exception handler at the entry point of you application. Read this post: [What is the entry point of swift code execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105690/what-is-the-entry-point-of-swift-code-execution) to understand what is the entry point of your iOS app.

Comment: the main issue is that i'm not getting any callback for handling this exception.

Answer (score 2):

I am observing this crash if Device date is changed

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, this is a development mode only assertion and should not occur in release mode.

See the implementation [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Firebase/InstanceID/FIRInstanceIDCheckinPreferences.m#L65).

Comment: Yeah I tested it in release mode. Everything works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you set device's date to something in the past.